# Angular/Jasmine: $httpBackend.expectGET works on Mac, not on Linux

Tags: linux, angularjs, jenkins, jasmine, protractor

I have the following setup to test a directive:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $injector) {
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

    var html = '<password-strength-bar password-to-check="password"></password-strength-bar>';
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    elm = angular.element(html);
    $compile(elm)(scope);

    $httpBackend.expectGET('l10n/en.js').respond({});
    $httpBackend.expectGET('tpl/page_signin.html').respond({});
}));
```

This works fine on a Mac. However, when I run the same code on Linux, it fails with the following error. It is a headless Linux box, but I'm using PhantomJS as my "browsers" in `karma.conf.js`.

```
Error: Unsatisfied requests: GET tpl/page_signin.html
```

I verified that both operating systems are using the same version of Node.

On a similar note, I've installed Chrome and Xfvb (via Jenkins) to run my e2e tests driven by Protractor. The following works fine when running on my Mac locally, but fails on Linux.

```
it('should render signup when user clicks on "Create one" link', function () {
    var signupLink = element(by.linkText('Create one'));
    expect(signupLink.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    signupLink.click();
    expect(element.all(by.css('.wrapper')).first().getText()).
        toMatch(/Hi there, we're so glad you're here./);
```

In Jenkins (on Linux), the error is:

```
    Failures:
    1) account signup should render signup when user clicks on "Create one" link
      Message:
    [31m    Expected '' to match /Hi there, we're so glad you're here./.[0m
      Stack:
        Error: Failed expectation
            at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myapp/workspace/tests/e2e/account.js:27:17)
            at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7)
```

Any idea why tests would run fine on Mac, but not on Linux?

Comment: Strangely enough, the unit test failure from Jenkins was correct. However, I was only able to reproduce it locally after "rm -rf bower_components".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be caused by using by.linkText('Create one') for my Protractor test. Once I added an id to the link and used by.id('create-account'), it worked.

I also found that using $('.alert') or by.css('alert') doesn't work nearly as well as by.id. Particularly when you click on a button and wait for something to appear on the next screen. For example:

```
var alert = element(by.id('success'));
browser.driver.wait(protractor.until.elementIsVisible(alert));
```

Comment: After working with this build a bit more, it turned out that using Firefox with Jenkins is much more reliable than Chrome.